# locally hosted WCF service can accessible in android using wifi

Tags: android, wcf, wifi

I have a wcf service which is hosted in my machine using IIS.

I made a one android application which is using wcf service using ksoap library.

When I am in developing mode, I can access the service using hosted URL.

**I want to know :
- If I install that android application on my mobile and want to connect with hosted wcf service using WIFI connection.
Is it possible or not ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If I install that android application on my mobile and connect to wcf service using WIFI connection. Is it possible or not ?

I'd say give it a try.

It should work, as long as you don't refer to `localhost` in your application, but use the host name or an internal or external IP address that maps to the IIS server.